# Multiple tasks in a single click function

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I am trying to write a prev/next page slider but i am having trouble moving some classes arround:

When i click next i want the active class to be removed from the first .number child and be passed on to the second, and then when i click next again the same process to be continued, i only got this to go forth one time, none the less, this process is needed to be done backwards for the Prev button, so, help?

the html

```
<div id="container">
     <button class="prev styledbtn">Prev</button>
     <button class="styledbtn number">1</button>
     <button class="styledbtn number">2</button>
     <button class="styledbtn number">3</button>
     <button class="styledbtn number">4</button>
     <button class="styledbtn number">5</button>
     <button class="next styledbtn">Next</button>
</div>
```

the css

```
body{
background:lavender;
}

#container{

width:300px;
height:100px;
background: whitesmoke;

}

.styledbtn{
outline:none;
border: 1px solid teal;
background:steelblue;
color: snow;
padding: 10px;
margin-right:-5px;

-webkit-transition: all 320ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
-moz-transition: all 320ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
 -o-transition: all 320ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
    transition: all 320ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); /* ease (default) */

-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
-moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
 -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); /* ease (default) */
}

.styledbtn:hover{
background:skyblue;
}

.active{
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
border:2px solid midnightblue;
}
```

and the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var one = $('.number').first().addClass('active');
    $('.next').click(function () {
        one.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    });
    $('.prev').click(function () {

    });
});
```

finally a pen of it [here](http://codepen.io/angus/pen/nJIxo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
  var numbers = $('.number');
  var one = numbers.first().addClass('active');

  $('.next').click(function(){
    numbers.filter(".active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
  });
```

or this :)

```
  var numbers = $('.number');
  var one = numbers.first().addClass('active');
      $('.next').click(function(){
         var currentActive = numbers.filter(".active");
         var nextNumber = currentActive.next();
         if(nextNumber.hasClass("number")){          
             currentActive.removeClass("active");
             nextNumber.addClass("active");
         } 
 });
```

for prev button you need change `next()` method call to `prev()`.

**UPDATE**

full script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var numbers = $('.number');
  var one = numbers.first().addClass('active');

  $('.next').click(function(){
         var currentActive = numbers.filter(".active");
         var nextNumber = currentActive.next();
         if(nextNumber.hasClass("number")){          
             currentActive.removeClass("active");
             nextNumber.addClass("active");
         }
  }); 

  $(".prev").click(function(){
         var currentActive = numbers.filter(".active");
         var prevNumber = currentActive.prev();
         if(prevNumber.hasClass("number")){          
             currentActive.removeClass("active");
             prevNumber.addClass("active");
         }
  });
});
```

Comment: works like a charm but the problem is that it adds the class .active to the next and prev buttons

Comment: @Miguel look at added code, I fix this small problem))

Comment: that removed the .active class all together :s

Comment: Works like a charm! Kudos!

Comment: @Benjamin, in documentation `filter() Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.`

Comment: Just curious if I use `.number` in different container will it affect that too

Comment: @Benjamin, in my example it effect on elements in `number` array

Comment: @Benjamin, if you want to reduce number array you can do something like this `var number = $("div.some-container").find(".number");`

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap both buttonfunctions (next and prev) into one function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var one = $('.number').first().addClass('active');
    $('.next,.prev').click(function () {
        var curr = $('button.active');
        if($(this).hasClass('next') )
            curr.next('.number').addClass('active');
        else
            curr.prev('.number').addClass('active');
        curr.removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

A working demo [**can be found here**](http://jsfiddle.net/un22d1pb/).

EDIT

Added some code, so that if there is no item next or previous, the first or last item will keep its active state

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var one = $('.number').first().addClass('active');
    $('.next,.prev').click(function () {
        var curr = $('button.active');
        if($(this).hasClass('next') ) {
            if( curr.next('.number').length > 0 ) {
                curr.next('.number').addClass('active');
                curr.removeClass('active');
            }
        }
        else {
            if( curr.prev('.number').length > 0 ) {
                curr.prev('.number').addClass('active');
                curr.removeClass('active');
            }
        } 
    });
});
```

[Also with a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/un22d1pb/5/).

Comment: This active even applies to next and previous button

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var one = $('.number').first().addClass('active');
    $('.next').click(function(){
        if(one.next('.number').length !=0){
            one.removeClass('active');
            one = one.next('.number').addClass('active');
        }
    });

    $('.prev').click(function(){
        if(one.prev('.number').length !=0){
            one.removeClass('active');
            one = one.prev('.number').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

or this other one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var one = $('.number').first().addClass('active');
    $('.next').click(function(){
        if(one.next().is('.number')){
            one.removeClass('active');
            one = one.next().addClass('active');
        }
    });

    $('.prev').click(function(){
        if(one.prev().is('.number')){
            one.removeClass('active');
            one = one.prev().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fjxbbpoq/) to see a working example.
Hope it useful!